# ksoap timeout behind proxy in android

Tags: android, proxy, socketexception, ksoap, envelope

i tried the example from http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data to get request and response from a wsdl service. its working fine when i tried in a proxyless. but when i work behind proxy,i get ***"The operation timed out:request time failed: java.net.SocketException"*** is there any way to set proxy to SoapObject or Soap Envelop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ksoap does not work behind a proxy. inorder to make that working..
download the HttpTransportSE.java and ServiceConnectionSE.java from sourceforge.

Create a package with HttpTransportSE and ServiceConnectionSE.

In ServiceConnectionSE constructor:

```
 String myProxy=android.net.Proxy.getDefaultHost() ;
            int myPort=android.net.Proxy.getDefaultPort();

            if(myProxy!=null){
                Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(myProxy, myPort));
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection(proxy);
            }
            else
            {
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
            }
```

now wherever we call HttpTransportSE.call()method make sure that it points to ur own package which has this two files.

Comment: Can you explain how to do it exactly as I have downloaded the files and copied these files in a new package but they are giving errors.Also can you give a link for these files.

Comment: @Waseem latest version of ksoap have proxy implemented in itself. so try to download the latest ksoap library.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Everyone , The latest version of KSOAP2.6.5 [Tested it and verified it] has fix for the proxy authentication issue . The `HTTPTransportSE` constructor now accepts `java.net.Proxy` instance as a parameter along with URL. The method will be like
 
            `HttpTransportSE httpTransport=new HttpTransportSE(proxy,URL);`

  If your proxy is configured and if it requires authentication then use
`Authenticator` class to setup your proxy credentials and have success. HTH , if not write me back

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you have to set up the proxy in android operating system settings themselves and it will work fine.

Comment: Nope i have done that..its not working.. thanks for ur answer

Answer (score 0):

Replace with this..

```
//Timeout in milliseconds

int timeout=60000;
AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport=new AndroidHttpTransport(url, timeout);
```