# Accessing BBC RSS feed on Android App

Tags: android, rss

I'm having some trouble reading two BBC feeds on my Android app, they both seem to time out. This is especially strange because all other feeds work fine using the exact same system. I guess if someone could test them in their Eclipse it might help me determine if my work's firewall/proxy is restricting access to this specific website.

The feeds are http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/weather/forecast/2159/Next3DaysRSS.xml and http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/england/kent/rss.xml.

I have other feeds being read with work fine e.g. http://www.kent.ac.uk/news/rss.html

The other strange thing is the chap next to me working on an iPhone under the same network restrictions is not having a problem.

**Any help would be greatly appreciated!**

For info here is the code I've been using to pull in feeds:

```
 HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
 HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 10000);


 // proxy settings
 String proxyHost = android.net.Proxy.getDefaultHost();
 int proxyPort = android.net.Proxy.getDefaultPort();

if(proxyPort != -1){
    params.setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, new HttpHost(proxyHost,proxyPort));
}

URL url = null;
        try {

            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

            url = new URL(feedUrl);

            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            // setting these timeouts ensures the client does not deadlock indefinitely
            // when the server has problems.
            conn.setConnectTimeout(2000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(2000);

            xr.setContentHandler(this);

    /* This is where it lurches indefinitely VVV */
            xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));




        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("RSS Handler IO", e.getMessage() + " >> " + e.toString());
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("RSS Handler SAX", e.toString());
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("RSS Handler Parser Config", e.toString());
        }
```

Comment: Getting this error --- 07-15 21:32:46.425: ERROR/RSS Handler IO(336): newsrss.bbc.co.uk/2.20.183.163:80 - Connection refused >> java.net.ConnectException: newsrss.bbc.co.uk/2.20.183.163:80 - Connection refused

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess you're having the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883896/ksoap-timeout-behind-proxy-in-android). Does it work if you take out the proxy settings? If that's the problem, I'd suggest writing the response stream to memory before feeding it to your XMLReader.

Comment: Didn't make a difference. I can view the feeds fine in Chrome and Safari, added proxy settings to emulator too and I can view them in the browser. So bizarre